# Why a placeholder for an optional property in the interface can only be of type any?

Tags: typescript

I have a file with a single declaration, which is the interface:

```
interface NamedPerson {
    firstName: string;
    age?: number;
    [propName: string]: any;
    greet(lastName: string): void;
}
```

It works fine as long as I keep the type of [propName: string]: **any**. If I change it to **number** or probably anything else, I get the error:

> [ts] Property 'greet' of type '(lastName: string) => void' is not assignable to string index type 'number'.

I want a new unspecified property of an object that uses NamedPerson interface to only be able to be of type **number**, not anything else.

**Question: What's wrong with the interface and how can I tailor it to my needs?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not need to be of type `any` but it need to be of a type that includes **all** other field type. In your case this would be `string` (due to `firstName`), `number` (due to `age`) and `(p: string) => void`  (due to `greet`)

```
interface NamedPerson {
    firstName: string;
    age?: number;
    [propName: string]: string | number | ((p: string)=> void);
    greet(lastName: string): void;
}
```

Typescript forces consistency between the index return type and the known fields (as the index can be used to return any of the known fields). You can create an inconsistent index if you use an intersection type:

```
type NamedPerson = {
    firstName: string;
    age?: number;
    greet(lastName: string): void;
} & {
    [propName: string]: number;
};
```

The problem is you will not be able to create such an object directly, you can only create it using `Object.assign` and a bit of type assertion:

```
let n: NamedPerson = Object.assign({
    firstName: "",
    age: 0,
    greet(lastName: string): void { }
}, {} as { [propName: string]: number });
```